# TypeError: null: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, mobile, error-handling, widget

When I tried to run flutter on chrome this error and a stack comes.

```
User
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building HomePage(dirty):
TypeError: null: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  HomePage
```

I can't copy and post the stack here because it has more lines than 3 thousand line I cannot post it here. Here is my HomePage:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                navigateToWalletPage(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Wallet'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                navigateToTransferPage(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Transfer'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  void navigateToWalletPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const WalletPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  void navigateToTransferPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const TransferPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ChatGPT told me the error is because of this line:

```dart
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

it used to be

```
const HomePage super(key: key);
```

but I changed it.

Comment: I put debugger on many files and firs time stop is in main.dart this expression runApp(const MyApp());

Comment: void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

Comment: then second stop is  return MaterialApp(

Answer (score 1):

`RaisedButton` is deprecated and
you should use `ElevatedButton` instead.
I did run your code in my machine with replacing the `RaisedButton` with `ElevatedButton` and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome help with my question! Your advice really saved the day, and I'm super grateful for your support.I really appreciate the time you took to explain .
Thanks again for being so cool and lending a hand. You're the best!

Catch you later,